# Why does Klaus need Elena's blood to create Hybrids?

Tags: vampire, the-vampire-diaries, hybrid

In *The Vampire Diaries*, we see a lot of supernatural things like vampires, werewolves, witches, doppelgängers and even hybrids. But what I don't get is why Klaus needs a doppelgängers blood to make hybrids and why he can't just use someone else's blood. And how come once the person is a vampire you can't use their blood anymore?  They have to be human and a doppelgänger?

Comment: It was Klaus' mother's trick.. To break the curse, Klaus needed to kill Doppelganger, but then a Doppelganger's blood was required to create hybrid. Klaus' mother wanted to make sure that Klaus wouldn't be able to create his hybrid army, but the things didn't play out her way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break the curse, Klaus needed to sacrifice a Doppelgänger, but they tricked him and saved Elena.

Now Elena is the missing key to create a hybrid, that's why Klaus needed her blood. Katherine's blood can't be used, as she is a vampire now. That curse required to sacrifice one vampire, one werewolf and one Doppelgänger. Now adding Katherine to the mix will mess up the equation.

Why a vampire Doppelgänger can't be used was never made clear. Maybe when a Doppelgänger becomes a vampire his Doppelgänger status become nulled.

Answer (score -2):

Klaus needs Elanas blood cause she is the doppelgänger and Klaus needs to sacrifice a doppelgänger to break the curse.  He tried using Katharine's blood but she was able to get away and turn herself making her vampire and klaus can only use a doppelgängers blood as long as he/she is human. Her blood is also key to making more hybrids.

Comment: I feel like I straight just copied @AnkitSharma answer. Sorry. If they look to similar go head and delete my answer :)